# disable -ffast-math at compile-time in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, xcode9

Hi There I am trying to use [sql amalgamation](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html) with my XCode project and I keep getting the following error. How do I disable `ffast math`?

> SQLite will not work correctly with the -ffast-math option of GCC.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Replace **-ffast-math** with **-ffp-mode=fast** or **-ffp-mode=std** where ever used.

-ffast-math results in behavior that is not fully compliant with the ISO C or C++ standard. However, numerically robust floating-point programs are expected to behave correctly. Arm recommends that you use the alias option -ffp-mode=fast instead of -ffast-math.
Hope it helps.